# Unrecognized element <app-engine-apis> means can't access legacy bundle services on Java 11+ GAE server

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, build.gradle, objectify, google-cloud-deploy

I finally migrated a long-running Google App Engine Java 8 project to Java 11+ standard environment before we lose Java 8 support in Jan 2024.

But I need to use the legacy bundled services including Datastore, Blobstore and Task Queues.  I should do this by 'Installing the App Engine API Jar.'

I followed the following Google tutorial https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java-gen2/services/access

In particular I need to 'Install the App Engine API JAR' by adding the following to the *app-engine.web.xml file*:

**<app-engine-apis>true</app-engine-apis>**

But trying to build/deploy the project via the Gradle plugin in Android Studio gets the exception 'Unrecognized element <app-engine-apis>'.

So alas - I can't deploy to the new Java 11 server environment while preserving the old bundled legacy functions.

Note: because I use the Gradle plugin with Android Studio to build and deploy the server, I don't have a pom.xml file used by Maven.

Any advice on how to build the server project using the necessary '<app-engine-apis>true</app-engine-apis>' embedded in the app-engine.web.xml would be deeply appreciated!  Specs below:

---

Android Studio Giraffe 2022.3.1 Patch 4 with Gradle 7.4.2

Running server on GAE Standard Environment with Objectify 5

AppEngine Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.endpoints-framework-server'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:2.4.2'
    }
}

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

appengine {
    deploy {
        version = "GCLOUD_CONFIG"
        projectId = "GCLOUD_CONFIG"
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

dependencies {
    implementation (group: 'com.google.appengine', name: 'appengine-api-1.0-sdk', version: '2.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.endpoints:endpoints-framework:2.2.2'
    implementation ('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.40.1') {
        exclude (group: 'httpclient', module: 'httpclient')
    }
    implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    implementation 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:3.0-alpha-1'
    implementation 'javax.activation:javax.activation-api:1.2.0'
    implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:8.1.0') {
        exclude (group: 'com.google.guava')
    }
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:31.0.1-jre'
    implementation (group: 'com.google.appengine.tools', name: 'appengine-gcs-client', version: '0.8.2')
    implementation 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:5.1.25'
    implementation "com.stripe:stripe-java:20.90.0"
}
```

app-engine.web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?\>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0"\>
    <application\>my-fashion-project\</application\>
    <version\>1\</version\>
    <runtime\>java11\</runtime\>
    <app-engine-apis\>true\</app-engine-apis\>   // THIS IS THE LINE THAT CAUSES EXCEPTION
    <threadsafe\>true\</threadsafe\>
    <url-stream-handler\>urlfetch\</url-stream-handler\>

<system-properties\>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties" /\>
    </system-properties\>

<sessions-enabled\>
        true
    </sessions-enabled\>

<resource-files\>
        <include path="/\*\*.json" /\>
    </resource-files\>

<automatic-scaling\>
        <min-instances\>1\</min-instances\>
   </automatic-scaling\>

</appengine-web-app\>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?\><web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5"\>
    <app-engine-apis\>true\</app-engine-apis\>

<filter\>
        <filter-name\>ObjectifyFilter\</filter-name\>
        <filter-class\>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter\</filter-class\>
    </filter\>
    <filter-mapping\>
        <filter-name\>ObjectifyFilter\</filter-name\>
        <url-pattern\>/\*\</url-pattern\>
    </filter-mapping\>

<servlet\>
        <servlet-name\>EndpointsServlet\</servlet-name\>
        <servlet-class\>com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet\</servlet-class\>
        <init-param\>
            <param-name\>services\</param-name\>
            <param-value\>
                com.myfashionserver.entities.MemberEndpoint,
                ............ (list of entity endpoints excluded) ............
            </param-value\>
        </init-param\>
    </servlet\>

<servlet-mapping\>
............ (list of servlets excluded) ............

<security-constraint\>
        <web-resource-collection\>
            <web-resource-name\>queue\</web-resource-name\>
            <url-pattern\>/queue/\*\</url-pattern\>
        </web-resource-collection\>
        <auth-constraint\>
            <role-name\>admin\</role-name\>
        </auth-constraint\>
    </security-constraint\>
    <welcome-file-list\>
        <welcome-file\>blog.html\</welcome-file\>
    </welcome-file-list\>
</web-app\>
```

Android Studio Gradle build exception log

```
com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Unrecognized element \<app-engine-apis\>
```

Comment: Maybe try upgrading your appengine-gradle-plugin version?

Comment: Hi stick - I've been trying to upgrade to the latest Gradle 8 but as usual, there's conflicts with other gradle dependencies that prevent complete upgrade.  The usual jigsaw puzzle of trying to fit legacy dependencies.  However I'll take your advice and try changing the Gradle again (Google doesn't mention which Gradle version is required to install the AppEngine API JAR).

Answer (score 0):

So I'll post the answer to this problem in case anyone else is also trying to update their GAE project to Java 11+ and tries to use the Legacy Bundled services and encounters the inability to build their App Engine standard project when using `<app-engine-apis>true</app-engine-apis>` in the appengine-web.xml file.

The problem is my GAE server project was using the original Cloud Endpoints Frameworks that conveniently created the server API stubs for the server and Android device client (see https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/about-cloud-endpoints-frameworks).

However Cloud Endpoints Framework uses the Java 8 environment.  The project is 'dead' on Github and has been abandoned for the newer Google Endpoints that uses the OpenAPI protocol.

So the problem was actually in the web.xml file where I specified the Endpoints servlet class to build the Endpoints servlets:

```
<servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet</servlet-class>
```

This servlet specification is required for the old Cloud Endpoints Framework along with the build.gradle dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.endpoints:endpoints-framework:2.2.2'
```

Using this framework prevents the `<app-engine-apis>true</app-engine-apis>` specification in the appengine-web.xml.  The project won't build.

My solution:  I just couldn't use the Legacy Bundled Services and instead was forced to update the GAE server to use the new Google Cloud Client Libraries with Cloud Storage and Datastore in Firebase.  The server database was already under the Firebase Datastore environment.

However what isn't clearly stated is that if you want to use Objectify with the newer Cloud Client Libraries, you must update the Objectify version to 6.  Any Objectify version under 6 will not work with the Cloud Client Libraries.

I believe this is good for the long run, because Google will eventually abandoned the Legacy Bundled services, and it would be foolish to build an entire database based on old APIs.  I am still using the Cloud Endpoints framework to build and deploy the project in a Java 17 environment now.  Eventually I'll have to implement the new Cloud Endpoints with openAPI but this will require a total rehaul of the Android, iPhone and web page client code - a very daunting task that will 'kill' any old versions of the client apps.

Hope this helps anyone in the same dilemma.

Comment: How did you update the GAE server to use the new Google Cloud Client Libraries with Cloud Storage and Datastore in Firebase?

Comment: Hi doctorram - I ended up upgrading the GAE server to the Java 17 environment but maintained the Cloud Endpoints Framework (and avoided OpenAPI for now).  It's straight-forward updating to Google Cloud Storage and Firebase Datastore.  The steps are: 1) update your Gradle/Maven dependencies to use GCS -> 2) MIGRATE TO OBJECTIFY 6 - which is essential for the new environment -> 3) Use the new GCS and Firebase APIs for Firebase bucket image service and upload -> 4) No need to change Task Queues just use new APIs.  Message me if you want any details on each step.  Should take 1 to 2 weeks of work.

Comment: Hi @stylesom, thanks for the response.  So, did you need to set `<app-engine-apis>true</app-engine-apis>` at all in your appengine-web.xml?  Don't the GCS and Firebase Datastore APIs still need that element in the Cloud Endpoints Framework with Java 17?

Comment: NO - I did not use the <app-engine-apis>true</app-engine-apis> in the appengine-web.xml.  You only specify this if you're using the legacy bundled services.  I did not use the legacy services and instead upgraded to the Firestore in Database mode - all the old entities, images and videos were already converted to the Firebase storage bucket and datastore so only needed to implement the new GCS and Firebase APIs without changing anything in the database.  Check the following link: [link]https://cloud.google.com/appengine/migration-center/standard/services/migrating-services.

Comment: And even though I don't use <app-engine-apis>true</app-engine-apis> in the appengine-web.xml any longer, I'm still able to use the appengine-framework API by implementing 'com.google.endpoints:endpoints-framework:2.2.2'.  This allows me to continue generating the REST endpointsDiscoveryDocs and avoid using OpenAPI for now.  However this old endpoints framework won't compile with Gradle Version 8.0 and higher.

Comment: Here are the new Gradle Dependencies for Firebase Datastore API:
    implementation platform('com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:26.28.0')
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-datastore'                         
    implementation 'com.googlecode.objectify:objectify:6.1.0'    
    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-tasks:2.31.0'                                       
    implementation 'com.sendgrid:sendgrid-java:4.10.1'. The last 2 are for cloud tasks (queries) and an external API to send emails to clients.

Comment: For new Entity 'database' APIs via Firebase Datastore: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/migration-center/standard/services/migrating-services?tab=java#top, https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/using-cloud-storage?tab=java, https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/using-firestore-in-datastore-mode?tab=java, https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java, and use Objectify 6 if applicable to your project.

Comment: For image/video service and upload you can reference https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/serving-static-files?tab=java#serving_files_from, but it's way easier to use the Firebase APIs that access the same storage bucket by implementing ('com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:8.1.0').  See https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start#java and https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start#web-namespaced-api.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I'd like to be specific:  I used to set <app-engine-apis>true</app-engine-apis> in the appengine-web.xml in my old Java 8 project.  But after upgrading to the Java 17 environment, I stopped specifying this in the appengine-web.xml and stopped using the legacy bundled services and instead upgraded all the datastore access, image/video access, and query tasks code to the new GCS and Firebase APIs along with Objectify 6.